# How do i make discount percentage of products in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to show a discount percentage of my products.

I get this error:

> Division by zero (0)

Can anyone suggest me that what's I'm doing wrong ?

```
@foreach ($Products as $product)
            <div>
                <span>{{ (($product->promo_price/$product->original_price) * 100) }}% <br />OFF</span>
                <img src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$product->image) }}" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <h2>{{ $product->title }}</h2>

                    <ins>  
<span>{{ $product->original_price }}DHs</span>
{{ $product->promo_price}}Dhs   
</ins>
            </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: The error says that you are trying to divide by zero, so for one of your products, `original_price` is equal to 0.

Comment: yes a i have products with empty original_price how i can avoid this error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that you have the original_price of some products equal to 0 or null.

You have to check before printing the discount to see if they have an `original_price`:

```
@foreach ($Products as $product)
    <div>
        @if ($product->original_price)
        <span>{{ (($product->promo_price/$product->original_price) * 100) }}% <br />OFF</span>
        @endif
        <img src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$product->image) }}" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>{{ $product->title }}</h2>

        <ins>  
            <span>{{ $product->original_price }}DHs</span>
            {{ $product->promo_price}}Dhs   
        </ins>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I added a condition on line 3 that will display the `<span>` with the discount only if you have an `original_price` for the product, and it is not equal to 0.

Comment: works fine.. thank you very much:) but in some products i get decimal like: 66.666666666667%

Comment: You can use the following function to round to X decimals: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-suggesting: You are dividing by zero, which is not allowed in ordinary arithmetic.

Check that `$product->original_price` has a value before using that as denominator, probably it is 0 or `null`

Comment: yes a i have products with empty original_price how i can make division if original_price is empty ?